# How to add a new column to a SQL database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm new to mobile development/Azure in general.

I'm following this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started) to set up an Azure backend that interfaces with a simple SQL database to an iOS app (written in Swift).

I've enabled offline sync (there is already prewritten code from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-offline-data). However, I am trying to add another column/variable of the number type to the SQL database. The steps I am doing is:

1. In Azure Easy Tables, I selected the database and added another column.
2. In my code, I changed the payload from

```
     let itemToInsert = ["text": text, "complete": false, "__createdAt": Date()] as [String : Any]

        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        self.table!.insert(itemToInsert) {
            (item, error) in
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: " + (error! as NSError).description)
            }
        }
```

to

```
       let itemToInsert = ["text": text, "complete": false, "__createdAt": Date(),"new_column":29] as [String : Any]

        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        self.table!.insert(itemToInsert) {
            (item, error) in
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            if error != nil {
                print("Error: " + (error! as NSError).description)
            }
        }
```

The new code runs, but the value of new_column is not showing up in the Easy Tables view on the Azure web portal. Does anybody have any suggestions?

I've read the following related questions:

1. [How to Add Columns to Easy Table for Azure Demo iOS App (Todo List)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621748/how-to-add-columns-to-easy-table-for-azure-demo-ios-app-todo-list)

It suggests cleaning the XCode build. I tried that and it didn't change anything.

2. [Swift Azure Mobile QuickStart - Add and sync PNG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863145/swift-azure-mobile-quickstart-add-and-sync-png-image?rq=1)

Didn't provide an answer.

Any help would be appreciated – thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but you're trying to change the table structure after the initial structure has been deployed.  I don't have any experience in Swift and therefore don't know what sort of APIs are available in those libraries. Having said that, I would drop the initial structure and have the app rebuild it. If dropping the table is not an option, I would add the column manually to through the portal.